# Cannot access to Fortigate FW through mgmt port after forming HA

Tags: firewall, ip-address, fortigate

The two FW are Fortigate WiFi 60E, OS v7.2.0 build1157.

The HA connection on the two FortiWifi60E was like

PC1-----Fortigate FW1-----Fortigate FW2-----PC2

PC1 IP:192.168.1.100

PC1 default gateway:192.168.1.99

heartbeat interface:1.1.1.1 & 1.1.1.2

PC2 IP:192.168.1.100

PC2 default gateway:192.168.1.98

I lost the connection on PC1 to FortiGate FW1 after forming HA, I changed the IP of PC1 to 192.168.1.101
and the FW2 interface IP to 192.168.1.98 to see if IP conflicts would cause such a problem. But it doesn't work out for me.

*The HA active-active / active-passive HA show the yellow light so I think HA is working.

*The following picture is the result of

get system ha status

IN fw1 with console port

[image: get system ha status IN fw1 with console port]

[image: [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M96rC.jpg]

ha status shown in FW2 GUI

Comment: *PC1-----Fortigate FW1-----Fortigate FW2-----PC2* That's not a HA setup. Also, please *never* use text screenshots. Instead, add text as text using the editor's `{}` preformat function.

Comment: @Zac67 
The FW1 and FW2 connect each other (heartbeat) to form HA, it just have PC connect to each of it.